# deleting sheets with a date older than the past two days

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Working in Google Scripts, I'm trying to create a function that will look at the names of all tabs in a Google Sheet, and delete all sheets that meet these conditions: 1) tab name include a date (sheet names that do have a date are prefaced with some other text - the mm/dd/yyyy formatted date is in the string) and 2) the date in that sheet name is older than today's date minus 2 days).

There are two sheet names that include dates: "Leadership Review mm/dd/yyyy" and "Leadership Review w/notes mm/dd/yyyy". I have a script that auto-runs DAILY to create these sheets, so the goal is to automate a one-time clean-up for old sheets and set up a daily trigger to auto-run that function.

So far, I've created an array to capture the names of each sheet name ("tabNameArray") and have a regexp for use in matching for mm/dd/yyyy text that shows up in a sheet name.

My thought on how this would work - not sure how to accomplish 2 and 3:

1. create that array
2. parse the array - match each sheetname in the array against the regexp mm/dd/yyyy to identify sheetnames with a date.
3. A loop through that array... IF that sheetname has a date (create a new array or subarray with just those? doesn't seem necessary, but a thought), AND that date is > 2 days from today(), delete those sheets.

```
function deleteOldReportSheets() {
  
  var sheetNameArray = new Array();
  var sheetWithDatesArray = new Array(); //not sure this is necessary
  var dateRegex = new RegExp("[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-3]?[0-9]\/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}"); //for mm/dd/yyyy match, tested successfully on regex101.com
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) sheetNameArray.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] ) // populates the sheetNameArray with names of each sheet

(do this: for sheets that have a date that is older than 2 days from today, delete...)
```

I'd appreciate support to code this - even better if there's a more efficient way than what I started thinking through.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

The following example will compare the named sheets containing the date to today and indicate which sheets should be deleted.  I leave the deletion operation to the OP.

**Script**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheets = spread.getSheets();
    let dateRegex = new RegExp("[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-3]?[0-9]\/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}"); //for mm/dd/yyyy match, tested successfully on regex101.com
    let today = new Date();
    console.log("today = "+Utilities.formatDate(today,"GMT","MM/dd/yyyy"));
    today = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-2);
    for( let i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
      let sheet = sheets[i];
      let name = sheet.getName();
      console.log("Sheet name = "+name);
      let match = name.match(dateRegex);
      if( match ) {
        match = new Date(match[0]);
        if( match.valueOf() <= today.valueOf() ) {
          console.log("delete");
        }
        else {
          console.log("keep");
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
11:45:16 AM Notice  Execution started
11:45:17 AM Info    today = 05/01/2022
11:45:17 AM Info    Sheet name = Sheet1
11:45:17 AM Info    Sheet name = Sheet 04/29/2022
11:45:17 AM Info    delete
11:45:17 AM Info    Sheet name = Sheet 04/30/2022
11:45:17 AM Info    keep
11:45:17 AM Info    Sheet name = Sheet 05/01/2022
11:45:17 AM Info    keep
11:45:16 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [String.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Comment: I went with the last suggestion in thread, thank you much for your time to respond, @TheWizEd.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const reg = new RegExp(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const if_two_days_ago = date =>
    new Date(date).valueOf() < new Date().valueOf() - 3600000 * 48;

  ss.getSheets()
    .filter(s => reg.test(s.getName()))
    .filter(s => if_two_days_ago(s.getName().match(reg)))
    .forEach(s => { console.log('bye-bye -->', s.getName()); ss.deleteSheet(s) });
}
```

Comment: I went with the last suggestion in thread, thank you much for your time to respond, Yuri.

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete Sheets with dates older than two days

```
function delSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() - 2).valueOf();//date threshold value
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    let m = sh.getName().match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/g);//includes a date
    if(m && new Date(m[0]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sh);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This was super efficient - worked as expected and thanks for the more elegant regex for mm/dd/yyyy match. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've been reading the latest version of Mastering Regular Expressions recently and I've started to use them with higher frequency.  But admittedly this one is a rather simple one.  I like the match because if it finds one using /g it returns it and it  can be used in following commands making it more useful programmatically.  This version will also match single digit days and months